# How do you use the spell tracker on Lamentations of the Flame Princess character sheet?

Tags: spells, spellcasting, character-sheets, lamentations-of-the-flame-princess

On the official character sheet of *Lamentations of the Flame Princess* (and on some fan-made sheets as well), the spell tracker looks like this:

[image]

How am I supposed to use this? I noticed that there's a dot per spell level (cleric spells go up to level 7 and magic-user spells go up to level 9), but I still don't understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure which official character sheet these fields appear in. In the [character sheet](http://www.lotfp.com/RPG/uploads/pdf/CharacterSheeta4.pdf) that I have seen, those fields look like this:

[image: Cast cleric spells and cast magic user spells fields]

The [free rules](http://www.lotfp.com/RPG/uploads/downloads/LotFP_WeirdFantasyRole-Playing_FREE.zip) include a section at the end that describes each section of the character sheet. The description for those fields are (page 90):

> [Cast Cleric Spells Field] Clerics can tick off what level spell they are able to cast, as determined on page 5.
>
> [Cast Magic User Spells Field] Magic-Users and Elves can tick off what level spell they are able to cast, as determined on page 10 and 17, respectively.

These fields are used to denote how many levels of spells you have unlocked. Since the number of dots in your image correspond to the number of spell levels for each Character Class, I believe they would be treated the same way and you would **fill in a dot for each unlocked spell level**.

Comment: I am using this character sheet which is hosted on the official LotFP website: http://www.lotfp.com/RPG/uploads/pdf/CharacterSheetGrindhouse.pdf. There's also the same thing on the official Veins of the Earth character sheet.

Anyway, thanks for your explanation even though it seems like a huge waste of space! Why not just write directly your max spell level?

Answer (score 2):

Note that every dot has a larger area (a triangle or an irregular quadrilateral) next to it. You can associate each dot with a spell level. You could try to fit in the number of spells per day of a given level into the empty space next to dot associated to the spell level, or just next to the dot and outside the diagram.

Or maybe there are there as art. Some people enjoy character sheets with all kinds of extraneous graphics, like the name or logo of the game.